# Convert Apache .htaccess to Nginx

Tags: apache, .htaccess, nginx, url-rewriting

I got the following .htaccess code for a Magento plugin, could someone help me convert it to valid Nginx rewrites? I'm having a really tough time getting this down. It's for a plugin that rewrites and caches Magento URL's.

The original editor of the module couldn't help me. I'm sure there are lots of people using Nginx and wanting to use this plugins functionality!

```
# static rewrite - home page
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} store=default
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !artio_mturbo=.*
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/magento/$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !.+
RewriteCond /var/ww/var/turbocache/default.html -f
RewriteRule .* var/turbocache/default.html [L]

# static rewrite - other pages
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} store=default
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !artio_mturbo=.*
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /magento/(.*)\.html$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !.+
RewriteCond /var/www/var/turbocache/magento/default/%1.html -f
RewriteRule .* var/turbocache/magento/default/%1.html [L]

# store view is choosen by request_path

# static rewrite - home page

RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !artio_mturbo=.*
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/magento/default(/|)$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !.+
RewriteCond /var/www/var/turbocache/default.html -f
RewriteRule .* var/turbocache/default.html [L]

# static rewrite - other pages
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !artio_mturbo=.*
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/magento/default/(.*)\.html$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !.+
RewriteCond /var/www/var/turbocache/magento/default/%1.html -f
RewriteRule .* var/turbocache/magento/default/%1.html [L]

#cookie
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !artio_mturbo=.*
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/magento/$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !.+
RewriteCond /var/www/var/turbocache/default.html -f
RewriteRule .* var/turbocache/default.html [L]

# rules for default storeview

# static rewrite - home page

RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !artio_mturbo=.*
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /magento/(.*)\.html$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !.+
RewriteCond /var/www/var/turbocache/magento/default/%1.html -f
RewriteRule .* var/turbocache/magento/default/%1.html [L]
```

Thanks so far!

Answer (score 3):

```
if ($http_cookie ~ "store=default"){
    set $rule_0 1$rule_0;
}
if ($http_cookie !~ "artio_mturbo=.*"){
    set $rule_0 2$rule_0;
}
if ($uri ~ "^/magento/$"){
    set $rule_0 3$rule_0;
}
if ($args !~ ".+"){
    set $rule_0 4$rule_0;
}
if (-f /var/ww/var/turbocache/default.html){
    set $rule_0 5$rule_0;
}
if ($rule_0 = "54321"){
    rewrite /.* /var/turbocache/default.html last;
}
if ($http_cookie ~ "store=default"){
    set $rule_1 1$rule_1;
}
if ($http_cookie !~ "artio_mturbo=.*"){
    set $rule_1 2$rule_1;
}
if ($uri ~* "/magento/(.*).html$"){
    set $rule_1 3$rule_1;
}
if ($args !~ ".+"){
    set $rule_1 4$rule_1;
}
if (-f /var/www/var/turbocache/magento/default/%1.html){
    set $rule_1 5$rule_1;
    set $bref_1 $1;
}
if ($rule_1 = "54321"){
    rewrite /.* /var/turbocache/magento/default/$bref_1.html last;
}
if ($http_cookie !~ "artio_mturbo=.*"){
    set $rule_2 1$rule_2;
}
if ($uri ~ "^/magento/default(/|)$"){
    set $rule_2 2$rule_2;
}
if ($args !~ ".+"){
    set $rule_2 3$rule_2;
}
if (-f /var/www/var/turbocache/default.html){
    set $rule_2 4$rule_2;
}
if ($rule_2 = "4321"){
    rewrite /.* /var/turbocache/default.html last;
}
if ($http_cookie !~ "artio_mturbo=.*"){
    set $rule_3 1$rule_3;
}
if ($uri ~* "^/magento/default/(.*).html$"){
    set $rule_3 2$rule_3;
}
if ($args !~ ".+"){
    set $rule_3 3$rule_3;
}
if (-f /var/www/var/turbocache/magento/default/%1.html){
    set $rule_3 4$rule_3;
    set $bref_1 $1;
}
if ($rule_3 = "4321"){
    rewrite /.* /var/turbocache/magento/default/$bref_1.html last;
}
if ($http_cookie !~ "artio_mturbo=.*"){
    set $rule_4 1$rule_4;
}
if ($uri ~ "^/magento/$"){
    set $rule_4 2$rule_4;
}
if ($args !~ ".+"){
    set $rule_4 3$rule_4;
}
if (-f /var/www/var/turbocache/default.html){
    set $rule_4 4$rule_4;
}
if ($rule_4 = "4321"){
    rewrite /.* /var/turbocache/default.html last;
}
if ($http_cookie !~ "artio_mturbo=.*"){
    set $rule_5 1$rule_5;
}
if ($uri ~* "/magento/(.*).html$"){
    set $rule_5 2$rule_5;
}
if ($args !~ ".+"){
    set $rule_5 3$rule_5;
}
if (-f /var/www/var/turbocache/magento/default/%1.html){
    set $rule_5 4$rule_5;
    set $bref_1 $1;
}
if ($rule_5 = "4321"){
    rewrite /.* /var/turbocache/magento/default/$bref_1.html last;
}
```

Hope it will work ,good luck。

Answer (score 1):

Here is a [converter](http://www.anilcetin.com/convert-apache-htaccess-to-nginx/) that give you this from your htaccess. This may give you a solid first base. After that, if you have further question please feel free to write them.

Comment: I got something back from that converter but it doesn't appear to give me back what I need? I see some variabeles but it doesn't seem to covert to what I need, or am I understanding something incorrect here?